# Php Memcache Design Patterns issue

Tags: php, caching, design-patterns, memcached

For a small home project I am working on I have been looking for OO design patterns for Memcache implementation, but so far haven't found something I feel fits, so maybe my approach is wrong.

I have a DB connection class and an baseModel class so I want to implement caching on the baseModel where appropriate.
I have implemented the Database connection and the Cacher as Singlton patterns.

I cannot seem to get the Cacher class to read the data or trigger the `echo "<p>Getting from cache";` line after I refresh the page on the base Model "loadFromDb" function

Here are the classes:

```
class Cacher {

protected static $cacher = null;
private static $settings;

public static function getCache() {
    if (self::$cacher != null) {
        return self::$cacher;
    }
    try {
        self::$settings = parse_ini_file("./configs/main.ini");
        self::$cacher = new Memcache();
        self::$cacher->connect(
            self::$settings['cache_server_host']
            , self::$settings['cache_server_port']
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // TODO log error and mitigate..
        echo "Error connecting memcache";
        die();
    }
    var_dump(self::$cacher->getstats());
    return self::$cacher;
}

public static function getData($key) {
    if (self::$cacher == null) {
        self::getCache();
    }
    return self::$cacher->get($key);
}

public static function setData($key, $data, $expire = 0) {
    if (self::$cacher == null) {
        self::getCache();
    }
    if (self::$cacher)
        return self::$cacher->set($key, $data, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, $expire);
}

}




class ModelBase {

protected $fields = array();
protected $class = null;

function __construct($class_name) {
    $this->class = $class_name;
    $this->fields = Database::getFields($class_name);
}

public function loadFromDB($id, $fromCache = true) {
    $key = "loadFromDB_{$this->class}_{$id}";

    if ($fromCache) {
        $data = Cacher::getData($key);

        if ($data) {
            echo "<p>Getting from cache";
            return unserialize($data);
        } else {
            echo "<p>No cache data. going to DB";
        }
    }
    $values = Database::loadByID($this->class, $this->fields[0], $id);

    foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
        $this->$key = $val;
    }
    $dataSet = Cacher::setData($key, serialize($this));
    echo "<p>Data set =  $dataSet";
}
```

}

Memcache service is running and I can read data directly back if I read the cache directly after I write it, but what I want is to read the data from the DB only the first time the page loads, after that use the cache....

Any comments welcome...

Comment: _Singleton_ is not considered a design pattern anymore...

Comment: Query the cache *first* -> if not found -> do your db -> store -> repeat

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like (let the result of the cache decide if you should query the db):

```
<?php 
public function loadFromDB($id) {
    $key = "loadFromDB_{$this->class}_{$id}";

    //query cache
    $data = Cacher::getData($key);

    //is it found
    if (!empty($data)) {
        //echo "<p>Getting from cache";
        return unserialize($data);
    } 
    //no so lest query db
    else {
        //echo "<p>No cache data. going to DB";
        $values = Database::loadByID($this->class, $this->fields[0], $id);

        foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }

        //store it in cache
        //$dataSet = Cacher::setData($key, serialize($this));
        $dataSet = Cacher::setData($key, serialize($values));//<<store the db result not the class
    }

    //echo "<p>Data set =  $dataSet";
    return unserialize($dataSet);
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried as suggested. `return unserialize($dataSet);` will try to unserialize the outcome of the memcache->set(key,val); a boolean, so it is not the answer. By the way 1 or true is returned so the cache is being written, I just returns null when I read it in `Cacher::getData($key)`

Comment: I was assuming the issue was a race condition o.O, can I make a suggestion that you do your de/serialization inside the methods `Cacher::getData($key)` & `Cacher::setData(*, *);` So it returns the datatype you gave it not serialized or null. This way you wont need to rely on validating and converting, what you put in you expect out... Also I suspect your do it on every call to them methods, so you might as well do it inside the method, remember DRY principle, also singletons are a bad practice, doing so hard codes the `Cacher` class into the methods and make it harder to unit test.

Comment: Hi Loz, I have it functioning as required now. I have tweeked it and got it going. Also moved the serialization out to the cacher.. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @bockymurphy glad you got it sorted.